# List category that only have product

Tags: django, django-views

I need to list only the category that have product. If a category don't have associated product, this category don't will be listed.

This my Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
catgories = Category.objects.filter(product__isnull=False)
# will return all those categories which have products
```

Comment: I agree: catgories = Category.objects.filter(product__isnull=False).distinct()
Thank you.